# Can I delete cnijpwgtmp files in /var/tmp?

Tags: tmp

My /var/tmp folder is 27 GiB.
Upon inspection, I've found hundreds of files starting with cnijpwgtmp (fi: cnijpwgtmpk6YaSu).

What are these files and can I delete them safely to restore space?

Comment: See this [Ubuntuforums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313775&page=2): That user had a scanner that was failing to delete the files. In their case, the files were safe to delete.

Comment: Specifically, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313775&s=65807db18fad4b7e0ce47b12ae48ed4a&p=13441497#post13441497

Comment: Thanks turned out it was some junk left by my scanner indeed. Removed the files to clean up my system.